# Passing a dataframe as an an argument in apply with pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to use `.apply()` with a dataframe as one of the arguments:

```
df.apply(func, axis=1, args=(df))
```

When I do, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Here is the function:

```
def func(df): 
  new_val = df.loc[ \
    (df["date"] == self.date + relativedelta(years=1)) & \
    (df["indicator"] == self.indicator), "val"]
  if (len(new_val) == 1):
    new_val = list(new_val)[0] # Extract integer from series
    self["updated_val"] =  new_val - self.val
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem here is the combination of `func` and `apply`. The `apply` method of a dataframe applies the given function to each COLUMN in the data frame and returns the result. So the function you pass to `apply` should expect a pandas Series or an array as input, not a dataframe. It should give either a series/array or single value as output. 
For example

```
df.apply(sum)
```

will apply the `sum` function to each column and give a series containing the
result for each column (normally you would do df.sum() for this but I'm just using it to illustrate the point).

Secondly, the `args` parameter in `apply` is only used when the function you are passing takes additional arguments (besides the series, which should be the first argument). For example, you might have a function that sums an array and then divides by some number (again a silly example):

```
def sum_div(array, divisor):
    return sum(array) / divisor
```

The you might want to apply this to each column of a dataframe with divisor = 2. 
You would do

```
df.apply(sum_div, args=[2])
```

I'm not sure what you want to here. Is it just `func(df)`?

Comment: Yes, it's `func(df)`.  Your explanation make sense, thanks